# Error importing gym using Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, openai-gym

I´m trying to run some code using Jupyter and I can´t find a way of installing gym.
This is the code:

```
!pip install gym==0.18
import gym
```

After all the "Requirement already satisfied"s (since I had already installed it) it says:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [2], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 get_ipython().system('pip install gym')
----> 2 import gym

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gym'
```

The same happens if I don´t specify a version, and use only "gym".
I tried installing it using Terminal several ways, however, this shouldn´t be so complicated, right?
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Strange! Can you run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` in the terminal & then verify if the "gym" library is showing up in the "requirements.txt" file or not?

Comment: It doesn´t show anything at all, just waits a couple of seconds and jumps to the next prompt.

Comment: that's because all the output is being stored into the "requirements.txt" file. Another way would be to just type `pip freeze` in the terminal and try to find `gym` in the terminal output.

Comment: I did that and I found a line: gym==0.18.0 but then I changed the environment to the one I´m trying to work with and I typed again pip freeze, however now I don´t see it. In fact, the file is just some lines long. If pip install gym once I´m in the new environment, doesn´t it have to be added to the requiremets.txt?

Comment: After seeing the results of pip freeze I typed again "install gym==0.18.0", and then I did again "pip freeze", and I can´t find it. I don´t know if after installing it should appear there.

Comment: maybe you have two Pythons installed and this `pip` installs modules for one Python but `Jupyter` runs code with other Python. And Pythons don't share modules. In code run `python( sys.executable )` to get `/full/path/to/python.exe` and later use this path to install modules `!/full/path/to/python.exe -m pip install ...`. BTW: You could also check if you have command `pip3` - and maybe it will also install modules for expected Python.